# Find the occurence of a character in a string

Tags: javascript

Could someone please tell me how to find the occurence of a character in a string? I have to check the number of lines getting displayed (using the br tag) in a dynamically created div. Thanks in advance,
Ashriya

Comment: I have to display some cities in the div. I bind these from the database, so I use the br tag to display them one by one. How can I check the no of cities getting displayed dynamically?

Comment: It's probably easier if you render the cities as a list of <li> if at all possible and then simply count the number of <li>s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use split and get the length of the array:

```
var div = document.getElementById('div');
alert(div.innerHTML.split(/\<br\s*\/\>/).length;
```

The `/\<br\s*\/*\>/` is a Regular Expression that looks for all `<br/>`, `<br />`

Comment: Hey Mic, since the /* is used for comments, its not working..:(

Comment: Remove it and use only `/\<br\s*\/\>/`

Answer (score 1):

You could try

[JavaScript indexOf() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)

or maybe use [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) and [array length](http://w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_array.asp).

Comment: I have to display some cities in the div. I bind these from the database, so I use the br tag to display them one by one. How can I check the no of cities getting displayed dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

string.indexOf('c')

Comment: I have to display some cities in the div. I bind these from the database, so I use the br tag to display them one by one. How can I check the no of cities getting displayed dynamically?

Answer (score -3):

SPLIT can be a good option as suggested by @astander

You can use Regular expression as well

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher; 
import java.util.regex.Pattern; 

public class javaRE { 
    public static void main(String[] args) { 

    String message = "Your contents";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("your character");
    Matcher matcher = p.matcher(message); 

    int count=0;
    while(matcher.find()&& matcher.group() != null){
        count++;
    }
    } 
}
```

Above code will help you to know the occurence of any character of substring or other pattern.

Best way

```
string.lastIndexOf('a');
```

Comment: java, javascript - same thing, who cares :P

Comment: I tried ur method but I don't understand what the "Pattern" and "Matcher" do. Could u help me with that please? Thanks.

Comment: Pattern is nothing but what you want to search. Above code was in java. I had wrote the whole program. Now you can run & test it without any change. I'll suggest if you try the last way i said ie lastindexof()